# Using xslt 10 i want to translate negative value to 0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For any occurance of negative value in the foll tag i want to replace it with 0.00
Input:   `<TaxAmount>-1.00</TaxAmount>`
Output: `<TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>`

Code snippet

```
<xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/TaxDetails/TaxDetail/TaxAmount">
        <TaxAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\-0123456789','0.00')"/>
        </TaxAmount>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Update:
XSLT used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TaxAmount[. &lt; '0']">
        <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/TaxDetails/TaxDetail/TaxAmount[number(.) &lt; 0]">
        <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/TaxDetails/TaxDetail/TaxAmount">
        <TaxAmount>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number(.) &lt; 0">0.00</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </TaxAmount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<tXML>
    <Header>
        <Source>X</Source>
        <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
        <Reference_ID>9999999</Reference_ID>
        <Message_Type>CustomerOrder</Message_Type>
        <Company_ID>1</Company_ID>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <OrderNumber>9999999</OrderNumber>
            <OrderCaptureDate>06/26/2015 14:59</OrderCaptureDate>
            <ExternalOrderNumber>9999999</ExternalOrderNumber>
            <OrderType>YYYY</OrderType>
            <OrderCurrency>X</OrderCurrency>
            <EntryType>NONE</EntryType>
            <Confirmed>TRUE</Confirmed>
            <PaymentDetails>
                <PaymentDetail>
                    <ExternalPaymentDetailId>X</ExternalPaymentDetailId>
                    <PaymentMethod>X</PaymentMethod>
                    <ReqAuthorizationAmount>41.65</ReqAuthorizationAmount>
                    <AccountNumber>1111111111</AccountNumber>
                    <ChargeSequence>1</ChargeSequence>
                    <BillToDetail>
                        <BillToFirstName>XX</BillToFirstName>
                        <BillToLastName>XX</BillToLastName>
                        <BillToAddressLine1>XX</BillToAddressLine1>
                        <BillToAddressLine2/>
                        <BillToCity>XX</BillToCity>
                        <BillToState>x</BillToState>
                        <BillToPostalCode>x</BillToPostalCode>
                        <BillToCountry>x</BillToCountry>
                        <BillToPhone>x</BillToPhone>
                        <BillToEmail>X</BillToEmail>
                    </BillToDetail>
                </PaymentDetail>
            </PaymentDetails>
            <ReferenceFields>
                <ReferenceField1>x</ReferenceField1>
                <ReferenceField10>x</ReferenceField10>
                <ReferenceField2/>
                <ReferenceField3>4</ReferenceField3>
                <ReferenceField4/>
                <ReferenceField8>STND</ReferenceField8>
            </ReferenceFields>
            <OrderLines>
                <OrderLine>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                    <ExternalLineID>x</ExternalLineID>
                    <ItemID>x</ItemID>
                    <Canceled>x</Canceled>
                    <AllocationInfo>
                        <RequiredCapacityPerUnit>1</RequiredCapacityPerUnit>
                    </AllocationInfo>
                    <PriceInfo>
                        <Price>41.65</Price>
                    </PriceInfo>
                    <Quantity>
                        <OrderedQty>1</OrderedQty>
                        <OrderedQtyUOM>ea</OrderedQtyUOM>
                        <CancelledQty>0</CancelledQty>
                    </Quantity>
                    <ShippingInfo>
                        <RequestedDeliveryBy>11/20/2015 23:59</RequestedDeliveryBy>
                        <ShipVia>X</ShipVia>
                        <ShippingAddress>
                        </ShippingAddress>
                    </ShippingInfo>
                    <ChargeDetails>
                        <ChargeDetail>
                        </ChargeDetail>
                    </ChargeDetails>
                    <TaxDetails>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>-0.07</TaxAmount>
                        </TaxDetail>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>0.01</TaxAmount>
                            <TaxDTTM>06/26/2015 14:59</TaxDTTM>
                        </TaxDetail>
                    </TaxDetails>
                </OrderLine>
        </OrderLines>
    </Order>
    </Message>
</tXML>
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can't just add (before) a `xsl:template match="/tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/TaxDetails/TaxDetail/TaxAmount[number(.) &lt; 0]">` that outputs `0.00` ? or an `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="number(.) &lt; 0">0.00</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>...` ?

Comment: @Max Please don't post code snippets - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry you mean it can't be added or can. Because I tried both the methods but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This shorter transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TaxAmount/text()[0 > .]">0.00</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<tXML>
    <Header>
        <Source>X</Source>
        <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
        <Reference_ID>9999999</Reference_ID>
        <Message_Type>CustomerOrder</Message_Type>
        <Company_ID>1</Company_ID>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <OrderNumber>9999999</OrderNumber>
            <OrderCaptureDate>06/26/2015 14:59</OrderCaptureDate>
            <ExternalOrderNumber>9999999</ExternalOrderNumber>
            <OrderType>YYYY</OrderType>
            <OrderCurrency>X</OrderCurrency>
            <EntryType>NONE</EntryType>
            <Confirmed>TRUE</Confirmed>
            <PaymentDetails>
                <PaymentDetail>
                    <ExternalPaymentDetailId>X</ExternalPaymentDetailId>
                    <PaymentMethod>X</PaymentMethod>
                    <ReqAuthorizationAmount>41.65</ReqAuthorizationAmount>
                    <AccountNumber>1111111111</AccountNumber>
                    <ChargeSequence>1</ChargeSequence>
                    <BillToDetail>
                        <BillToFirstName>XX</BillToFirstName>
                        <BillToLastName>XX</BillToLastName>
                        <BillToAddressLine1>XX</BillToAddressLine1>
                        <BillToAddressLine2/>
                        <BillToCity>XX</BillToCity>
                        <BillToState>x</BillToState>
                        <BillToPostalCode>x</BillToPostalCode>
                        <BillToCountry>x</BillToCountry>
                        <BillToPhone>x</BillToPhone>
                        <BillToEmail>X</BillToEmail>
                    </BillToDetail>
                </PaymentDetail>
            </PaymentDetails>
            <ReferenceFields>
                <ReferenceField1>x</ReferenceField1>
                <ReferenceField10>x</ReferenceField10>
                <ReferenceField2/>
                <ReferenceField3>4</ReferenceField3>
                <ReferenceField4/>
                <ReferenceField8>STND</ReferenceField8>
            </ReferenceFields>
            <OrderLines>
                <OrderLine>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                    <ExternalLineID>x</ExternalLineID>
                    <ItemID>x</ItemID>
                    <Canceled>x</Canceled>
                    <AllocationInfo>
                        <RequiredCapacityPerUnit>1</RequiredCapacityPerUnit>
                    </AllocationInfo>
                    <PriceInfo>
                        <Price>41.65</Price>
                    </PriceInfo>
                    <Quantity>
                        <OrderedQty>1</OrderedQty>
                        <OrderedQtyUOM>ea</OrderedQtyUOM>
                        <CancelledQty>0</CancelledQty>
                    </Quantity>
                    <ShippingInfo>
                        <RequestedDeliveryBy>11/20/2015 23:59</RequestedDeliveryBy>
                        <ShipVia>X</ShipVia>
                        <ShippingAddress>
                        </ShippingAddress>
                    </ShippingInfo>
                    <ChargeDetails>
                        <ChargeDetail>
                        </ChargeDetail>
                    </ChargeDetails>
                    <TaxDetails>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>-0.07</TaxAmount>
                        </TaxDetail>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>0.01</TaxAmount>
                            <TaxDTTM>06/26/2015 14:59</TaxDTTM>
                        </TaxDetail>
                    </TaxDetails>
                </OrderLine>
        </OrderLines>
    </Order>
    </Message>
</tXML>
```

**Produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<tXML>
    <Header>
        <Source>X</Source>
        <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
        <Reference_ID>9999999</Reference_ID>
        <Message_Type>CustomerOrder</Message_Type>
        <Company_ID>1</Company_ID>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <OrderNumber>9999999</OrderNumber>
            <OrderCaptureDate>06/26/2015 14:59</OrderCaptureDate>
            <ExternalOrderNumber>9999999</ExternalOrderNumber>
            <OrderType>YYYY</OrderType>
            <OrderCurrency>X</OrderCurrency>
            <EntryType>NONE</EntryType>
            <Confirmed>TRUE</Confirmed>
            <PaymentDetails>
                <PaymentDetail>
                    <ExternalPaymentDetailId>X</ExternalPaymentDetailId>
                    <PaymentMethod>X</PaymentMethod>
                    <ReqAuthorizationAmount>41.65</ReqAuthorizationAmount>
                    <AccountNumber>1111111111</AccountNumber>
                    <ChargeSequence>1</ChargeSequence>
                    <BillToDetail>
                        <BillToFirstName>XX</BillToFirstName>
                        <BillToLastName>XX</BillToLastName>
                        <BillToAddressLine1>XX</BillToAddressLine1>
                        <BillToAddressLine2/>
                        <BillToCity>XX</BillToCity>
                        <BillToState>x</BillToState>
                        <BillToPostalCode>x</BillToPostalCode>
                        <BillToCountry>x</BillToCountry>
                        <BillToPhone>x</BillToPhone>
                        <BillToEmail>X</BillToEmail>
                    </BillToDetail>
                </PaymentDetail>
            </PaymentDetails>
            <ReferenceFields>
                <ReferenceField1>x</ReferenceField1>
                <ReferenceField10>x</ReferenceField10>
                <ReferenceField2/>
                <ReferenceField3>4</ReferenceField3>
                <ReferenceField4/>
                <ReferenceField8>STND</ReferenceField8>
            </ReferenceFields>
            <OrderLines>
                <OrderLine>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                    <ExternalLineID>x</ExternalLineID>
                    <ItemID>x</ItemID>
                    <Canceled>x</Canceled>
                    <AllocationInfo>
                        <RequiredCapacityPerUnit>1</RequiredCapacityPerUnit>
                    </AllocationInfo>
                    <PriceInfo>
                        <Price>41.65</Price>
                    </PriceInfo>
                    <Quantity>
                        <OrderedQty>1</OrderedQty>
                        <OrderedQtyUOM>ea</OrderedQtyUOM>
                        <CancelledQty>0</CancelledQty>
                    </Quantity>
                    <ShippingInfo>
                        <RequestedDeliveryBy>11/20/2015 23:59</RequestedDeliveryBy>
                        <ShipVia>X</ShipVia>
                        <ShippingAddress>
                        </ShippingAddress>
                    </ShippingInfo>
                    <ChargeDetails>
                        <ChargeDetail>
                        </ChargeDetail>
                    </ChargeDetails>
                    <TaxDetails>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
                        </TaxDetail>
                        <TaxDetail>
                            <TaxAmount>0.01</TaxAmount>
                            <TaxDTTM>06/26/2015 14:59</TaxDTTM>
                        </TaxDetail>
                    </TaxDetails>
                </OrderLine>
        </OrderLines>
      </Order>
    </Message>
</tXML>
```

---

**Explanation**:

This solution uses the most general and powerful XSLT design pattern of overriding the *[**identity rule**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)*.

The overriding template matches any text node that is a child of a `TaxAmount` element, and whose string value (of the text node), when converted to number, is less than `0`. It simply replaces the matched node by a new one, whose string value is the string `0.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also have the *identity transform* template in place, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="TaxAmount[. &lt; 0]">
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TaxAmount[. &lt; 0]">
    <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tXML>
   <Header>
      <Source>X</Source>
      <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
      <Reference_ID>9999999</Reference_ID>
      <Message_Type>CustomerOrder</Message_Type>
      <Company_ID>1</Company_ID>
   </Header>
   <Message>
      <Order>
         <OrderNumber>9999999</OrderNumber>
         <OrderCaptureDate>06/26/2015 14:59</OrderCaptureDate>
         <ExternalOrderNumber>9999999</ExternalOrderNumber>
         <OrderType>YYYY</OrderType>
         <OrderCurrency>X</OrderCurrency>
         <EntryType>NONE</EntryType>
         <Confirmed>TRUE</Confirmed>
         <PaymentDetails>
            <PaymentDetail>
               <ExternalPaymentDetailId>X</ExternalPaymentDetailId>
               <PaymentMethod>X</PaymentMethod>
               <ReqAuthorizationAmount>41.65</ReqAuthorizationAmount>
               <AccountNumber>1111111111</AccountNumber>
               <ChargeSequence>1</ChargeSequence>
               <BillToDetail>
                  <BillToFirstName>XX</BillToFirstName>
                  <BillToLastName>XX</BillToLastName>
                  <BillToAddressLine1>XX</BillToAddressLine1>
                  <BillToAddressLine2/>
                  <BillToCity>XX</BillToCity>
                  <BillToState>x</BillToState>
                  <BillToPostalCode>x</BillToPostalCode>
                  <BillToCountry>x</BillToCountry>
                  <BillToPhone>x</BillToPhone>
                  <BillToEmail>X</BillToEmail>
               </BillToDetail>
            </PaymentDetail>
         </PaymentDetails>
         <ReferenceFields>
            <ReferenceField1>x</ReferenceField1>
            <ReferenceField10>x</ReferenceField10>
            <ReferenceField2/>
            <ReferenceField3>4</ReferenceField3>
            <ReferenceField4/>
            <ReferenceField8>STND</ReferenceField8>
         </ReferenceFields>
         <OrderLines>
            <OrderLine>
               <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
               <ExternalLineID>x</ExternalLineID>
               <ItemID>x</ItemID>
               <Canceled>x</Canceled>
               <AllocationInfo>
                  <RequiredCapacityPerUnit>1</RequiredCapacityPerUnit>
               </AllocationInfo>
               <PriceInfo>
                  <Price>41.65</Price>
               </PriceInfo>
               <Quantity>
                  <OrderedQty>1</OrderedQty>
                  <OrderedQtyUOM>ea</OrderedQtyUOM>
                  <CancelledQty>0</CancelledQty>
               </Quantity>
               <ShippingInfo>
                  <RequestedDeliveryBy>11/20/2015 23:59</RequestedDeliveryBy>
                  <ShipVia>X</ShipVia>
                  <ShippingAddress/>
               </ShippingInfo>
               <ChargeDetails>
                  <ChargeDetail/>
               </ChargeDetails>
               <TaxDetails>
                  <TaxDetail>
                     <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
                  </TaxDetail>
                  <TaxDetail>
                     <TaxAmount>0.01</TaxAmount>
                     <TaxDTTM>06/26/2015 14:59</TaxDTTM>
                  </TaxDetail>
               </TaxDetails>
            </OrderLine>
         </OrderLines>
      </Order>
   </Message>
</tXML>
```

Comment: I have used this technique but it doesn't seem to work. I have used the one you suggested and this as well. `TaxAmount[number(.) &lt; 0]`

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is a useless description. What we need to see is a **reproducible** example, including the input, the attempted XSLT and the expected result. Please add these to your question.

Comment: I have added the xslts attempted and the input xml.

Comment: @Max You have too much code, but even so you should be getting the expected output - assuming the expected output is the result that I have now added to my answer.